# Highcharts heatmap does not render correct colours according to specified colour stops

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

On a Highcharts heat map I specify the data in JSON format as follows:

```
                    var dataJson = [];
                    if (model.ActivityData != undefined) {
                        var index = 0;
                        if (model.ActivityData.length > 0) {
                            model.ActivityData.forEach(function(timeLineItem) {
                                dataJson.push({
                                    x: $scope.getChartDate(timeLineItem.Date.split("T")[0]),
                                    y: timeLineItem.IndicatorMeasure,
                                    value: Math.round(timeLineItem.Amount * 100) / 100,
                                    name: $scope.getChartDate(timeLineItem.Date.split("T")[0]),
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

"Value" is always between 0 and 1. I have added a tooltip showing "value" when hovering over a point.

I specify the colour stops as follows (it is

Orange: 0
White: 0.5
Green: 1

```
                                    colorAxis: {
                                    stops: [
                                        [0, '#F9A847'],
                                        [0.5, '#ffffff'],
                                        [1, '#b1d4b1']
                                    ]
                                },
```

I would expect any values below 0.5 to be a shade of orange and any values over 0.5 to be a shade of green. However when the chart is rendered some values above 0.5 are orange.

Does Highcharts use "value" explicitly to set the colour and if so, why is it not respecting the specified colour tops. Or does highcharts adjust the colours by averaging (or something similar) to determine the colours.

[image]

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/n4p3xh73/2/).

As you can see from the color axis, it extends from 0.4 to 0.7, which means that your middle color stop is actually as 0.55 in terms of axis values. The axis extremes is based on the data values.

So in order to make the axis extend from 0 to 1, like you probably expect, you need to set min and max. [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/n4p3xh73/1/).

```
colorAxis: {
    stops: [
        [0, '#F9A847'],
        [0.5, '#ffffff'],
        [1, '#b1d4b1']
    ],
    min: 0,
    max: 1
},
```

Comment: @Torstein Hønsi how can i divide color axis from -infinite < 0 && 0< + infinite ? i want a break point exactly on zero and change the color . for example from dark red to white and white to dark green color range

Comment: @torstein how can I do this if the data contains negative values. I would want positive values to be shades of green and negative values to be shades of orange